# Protected Routes and searchParams in Nextjs version 13

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, next.js, next-auth

I'm trying to implement google authentication using next-auth in next js. It is implemented but now I'm trying to handle the scenario where authentication is failed and it is redirected to the `/login` with some error in the params. I can get this error from the search params in `<Login />`. But the problem is, in my layout.tsx, to implement protected routes I have this login where in the session in empty, it redirect to the `<Login/>` component. So in case when authentication fails and it redirects to the `<Login/>` with error in the params, because the session in null, layout.tsx again redirects it to `<Login/>` with no params.
I tried to have the logic to check search params in the layout.tsx, but its always null there.

How can I implement it perfectly?

layout.tsx:

```
import './globals.css'
import { redirect } from 'next/navigation'
import { Poppins } from 'next/font/google'
import Sidebar from './components/Sidebar'
import Topbar from './components/Topbar'
import Footer from './components/Footer'
import { NextAuthProvider } from "./providers";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth";
import { authOptions } from "@/lib/auth";
import Login from './login/page'


const fonts = Poppins({
  weight: ['400'],
  subsets: ['latin']
})

export const metadata = {
  title: 'Khaata',
  description: 'Devsinc Khaata',
}

type LoginPagePropsType = {
  searchParams?: {
    error: string
  }
}

export default async function RootLayout({ children, searchParams }: { children: React.ReactNode, searchParams?: LoginPagePropsType }) {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
  console.log("Search Params In layout", searchParams);

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={`${fonts.className} class="m-0 text-base antialiased font-normal dark:bg-slate-900 leading-default bg-gray-50 text-slate-500"`}>
        <NextAuthProvider>
          {(!searchParams) && (
            <>
              {(session) && (
                <>
                  <div className="absolute w-full bg-blue-500 dark:hidden min-h-75"></div>
                  <Sidebar />
                  <main className="relative h-full max-h-screen transition-all duration-200 ease-in-out xl:ml-68 rounded-xl">
                    <Topbar />
                    <div className="w-full px-6 py-6 mx-auto">
                      {children}
                    </div>
                    <Footer />
                  </main>
                </>
              )}

              {(!session) && (
                <Login />
              )}
            </>
          )}
        </NextAuthProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

Login component:

```
import { LoginButton } from "../components/buttons.component";

type LoginPagePropsType = {
  searchParams?: {
    error: string
  }
}

async function Login({ searchParams }: LoginPagePropsType) {
  console.log("searchParams", searchParams);

  const error = searchParams?.error
  console.log("Error", error);

  if (error) {
    console.log("Error in condition", error);

    return (
      <div>Error</div>

    )
  }

  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen bg-gray-100 py-6 flex flex-col justify-center sm:py-12">
      <div className="relative py-3 sm:max-w-xl sm:mx-auto">
        <div className="absolute inset-0 bg-gradient-to-r from-teal-400 to-blue-500 shadow-lg transform -skew-y-6 sm:skew-y-0 sm:-rotate-6 sm:rounded-3xl"></div>
        <div className="relative px-4 py-10 bg-white shadow-lg sm:rounded-3xl sm:p-20">
          <h1 className="text-2xl font-semibold text-center text-gray-800 mb-6">Login to Your Account</h1>
          <div className="w-full px-6 py-2  flex justify-center" >
            <LoginButton />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

I've tried to have the logic to check search params in the layout.tsx, but its always null in there.

Comment: protected route is usually implemented in middleware file in next.js

Comment: I configured middleware but in the url I always get favcon.ico

My code is:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";

export async function middleware(request: 
NextRequest) {
  console.log("req", request.nextUrl.pathname);
  const { url } = request;
  let isLogin = false;
  if (!isLogin) {
    if (!request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith("/login")) {
      return NextResponse.rewrite(new URL("/login", request.url));
    }
  } else {
    // will handle
    }
  }
}

```